# websphere path of installedApps directory

Tags: java, websphere

Java
How I get path of websphere installedApps directory?

I use

```
String webSphereAppsPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath()
```

Result:

> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer2\profiles\AppSrv01

I need result:

> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer2\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\BASTIONNode01Cell

Comment: perhaps you should look at WebSphere variables.  (in your Systems Console)

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Application binary settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rapp_appbin.html) topic in the Knowledge Center, you want `${APP_INSTALL_ROOT}/${CELL}`. See the [Creating, editing, and deleting WebSphere variables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tcws_variable.html) topic for sample code on expanding this variable.

(That said, I suspect directly accessing this directory is the wrong approach.  You should probably consider asking a new question along the lines of "What is the best way to do X?  I can accomplish it by looking at the installedApps directory, but it seems like there should be a better way.")

Comment: I use this code for solution of the problem  

`String clientFileName = "statCS.war";   
   String webSphereLibPath = StatMgr.class.getResource(ContextListener.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString();
   String clientWebSphereFilePath = webSphereLibPath.substring("file:/".length(), webSphereLibPath.indexOf(clientFileName) + clientFileName.length()); 
`

Comment: String manipulation and hard-coding your application name (and relying on this directory at all) seem fragile, but I'm glad you found some solution that works for you.